# Make.com - Google Forms module doesn't register new answers in a form

Tags: automation, make.com, integromat-apps

I'm trying to create a simple automation with a few modules, starting with Google Forms `Watch Responses` module. It has the `Choose where to start from` menu, with the `From now on` ticked by default.

First problem is that the first option `From now on` stays ticked even when I select other option and save, it always ticks back. However, selecting other option **only works one time**, one run of the scenario. For example, if I select `All`, it successfully gets all of the answers, but that means duplicates later on.

As this module is the only `WATCH` module that Make offers, I have no other option but to use it. Should I go for a workaround? Use a different app? Is the problem on Google's side?